# Word counting program using multi threading: Large file size

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am trying to write a program which will count words in a large file. I am doing multi threading. But my program gives segmentation fault and I am just stuck here. I am looking for any advice from mentors: The code is given below:

INPUT: `file name`
Output: Segmentation Fault

**The code is:**

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct thread_data{
    FILE *fp;
    long int offset;
    int start;
    int blockSize;
};

int words=0;  

void *countFrequency(void* data){

    struct thread_data* td=data;
    char *buffer = malloc(td->blockSize);

    int i,c;
    i=0;c=0;
    enum states { WHITESPACE, WORD };
    int state = WHITESPACE;

    fseek(td->fp, td->offset, td->start);

        char last = ' '; 
        while ((fread(buffer, td->blockSize, 1, td->fp))==1){

            if ( buffer[0]== ' ' || buffer[0] == '\t'  ){
            state = WHITESPACE;
            }
            else if (buffer[0]=='\n'){
            //newLine++;
                state = WHITESPACE;
            }
            else {
                if ( state == WHITESPACE ){
                    words++;
                }
                state = WORD;
            }
            last = buffer[0];
    }
    free(buffer);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int nthreads, x, id, blockSize,len;
    //void *state;
    FILE *fp;
    pthread_t *threads;

    struct thread_data data[nthreads];

    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./a.out <file_path>");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(-1);
    }  

    printf("Enter the number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d",&nthreads);
    threads = malloc(nthreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);  
    printf("len= %d\n",len);

    blockSize=(len+nthreads-1)/nthreads;
    printf("size= %d\n",blockSize);

    for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++){

        data[id].fp=fp;
        data[id].offset = blockSize;
        data[id].start = id*blockSize+1;

        }
        //LAST THREAD
        data[nthreads-1].start=(nthreads-1)*blockSize+1;

        for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
            pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &countFrequency,&data[id]);

    for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
        pthread_join(threads[id],NULL);

    fclose(fp);
    //free(threads);

    //pthread_exit(NULL);

    printf("%d\n",words); 
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Aside from your error, it won't be a good idea to use multi-threading in the case you read from a file in the disk. Your program performance would be bound already by slow reading from the file.

Comment: It would be better if you added the line numbers in your code.

Answer (score 3):

*Typecasting does not fix wrong code* - it only disguises it or makes it even more wrong. Let's look at those errors:

```
struct thread_data* td=(struct thread_data)data; /* wrong */
```

You can't cast a `struct thread_data *` to a `struct thread_data`, neither can you assign a `struct thread_data` to a `struct thread_data *`. The incorrect *and* unnecessary cast is the sole cause of the error.

```
x = pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &countFrequency, (void *)data); /* wrong */
```

Secondly, nor can you cast a `struct thread_data` to a `void *` - you need an actual pointer, like the *address* of `data`:

```
x = pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &countFrequency, &data);
```

No cast, either, because pointers to data types convert to `void *` naturally. Of course, since there's only one copy of `data` all the threads are going to share it, and all work on whatever the last values written to it were. That's not going to go well - you'll want one `struct thread_data` per thread.

Thirdly, those warnings are telling you your thread function has the wrong signature:

```
void *countFrequency(struct thread_data *data) /* wrong */
```

Combined with the first point, get all the types correct and yet again no casts are needed.

```
void *countFrequency(void *data) {
    struct thread_data* td = data;
```

Comment: +1 Some variation of the things you touched upon constitute a healthy chunk of all `pthreads` questions asked here.

Comment: @Notlikethat: Thank You, very much. I must admit that I am still a beginner in pointer issues as well as in thread issues. According to your advice, I modified my code, But now Segmentation Fault arises. Can you advice me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @user2015915 What value does `nthreads` have when `data[nthreads]` is allocated? Learn to use your debugger to pinpoint _when_ and _where_ the fault happens, which will go most of the way towards telling you _why_.