# C Multithreaded Word count

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, word-count

So I'm working on a multithreaded word count program in c and I was having some problems with my code, while searching here I found an old question that was similar to my own project. Rather than trying to rework my code which was full of problems, I decided to try and get this other one working, then modify it to make what I want.
The code takes a txt file as input. The problem is when you run the program there is a segmentation fault.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct thread_data{
    FILE *fp;
    long int offset;
    int start;
    int blockSize;
};

int words=0;  

void *countFrequency(void* data){

    struct thread_data* td=data;
    char *buffer = malloc(td->blockSize);

    int i,c;
    i=0;c=0;
    enum states { WHITESPACE, WORD };
    int state = WHITESPACE;

    fseek(td->fp, td->offset, td->start);

    char last = ' '; 
    while ((fread(buffer, td->blockSize, 1, td->fp))==1){

        if ( buffer[0]== ' ' || buffer[0] == '\t'  ){
        state = WHITESPACE;
        }
        else if (buffer[0]=='\n'){
            state = WHITESPACE;
        }
        else {
            if ( state == WHITESPACE ){
                words++;
            }
            state = WORD;
        }
        last = buffer[0];
    }
    free(buffer);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int nthreads, id, blockSize,len;
    FILE *fp;
    pthread_t *threads;


    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./a.out <file_path>");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(-1);
    }  

    printf("Enter the number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d",&nthreads);
    struct thread_data data[nthreads];
    threads = malloc(nthreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);  
    printf("len= %d\n",len);

    blockSize=(len+nthreads-1)/nthreads;
    printf("size= %d\n",blockSize);

    for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++){

        data[id].fp=fp;
        data[id].offset = blockSize;
        data[id].start = id*blockSize+1;

    }

    data[nthreads-1].start=(nthreads-1)*blockSize+1;

    for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
        pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, &countFrequency,&data[id]);

    for(id = 0; id < nthreads; id++)
        pthread_join(threads[id],NULL);

    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d\n",words); 
    return 0;  
}
```

And here's a link to the original post: [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355220/word-counting-program-using-multi-threading-large-file-size)

Comment: I guess you will need some code for exclusive control for reading the file.

Comment: What is the meaning of the strikethrough sentence? Also, while clarifying these things, please also reduce your example to the smallest possible size. For example, is using multiple threads necessary at all?

Comment: The strikethrough was because my original question was different, for that question the full code was necessary, as is the multithreading for what I'm trying to do. Anyway, I've decided to start fresh because I've figured out a better way to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using indeterminate value of uninitalized variable having automatic storage duration `nthreads` in `struct thread_data data[nthreads];`.

Try moving the line after `scanf("%d",&nthreads);`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I have problem with the countFrequency function. The global variable words is never getting incremented, I suppose something must be wrong with my if/else statement logic but I don't know.

Comment: Actually the problem is most likely in the while statement. I looked into the fread function and it apparently returns a size_t variable rather than a success/fail as I assumed. So my question is how I could do the equivalent of a input.hasNext() (c++) in that while loop?